# How can the U.S. government ensure that the black budget is spent appropriately?

Tags: united-states, budget

The black budget is a secret budget for covert operation. How can the U.S. government ensure that the money is spent appropriately and people don't spend it for personal reasons or other reasons not related to national security or protects the national interests of the country.

Comment: The whole point of doing things off the books is to avoid oversight, so the question answers itself, IMO.

Comment: You may want to read about the Church Committee, if you haven't https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_Committee

Comment: They can't even ensure that the regular defense budget is spent appropriately!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Such a budget will, inevitably, fall under an executive department, headed by either a Cabinet Secretary, or the President himself.  The budget for that department is scrutinised by Congressional Committees.

Both the relevant Cabinet Secretary, and the senior members of the relevant Congressional Committees, are allowed to know about relevant classified information (including details of such operations), and to scrutinise in a way they see fit.  They just have to keep this secret.

Comment: For this reason diverse agencies have black accounts which are not budgets and therefore are even further away from oversight

Comment: *"scrutinise in a way they see fit"* and what can they do if they don't like it, if they can't affect it due to secrecy?

Comment: @vsz: The reviewers are often the people who allocate money _into_ the budget. If it's misused, these reviewers can withhold money from that budget.  Other reviewers are the people who manage the people who do the spending. If it's misused, these reviewers will _fire_ the people who spent the money. The reviewers may also have authority to _imprison_ abusers.

Comment: @MooingDuck "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boland_Amendment" Pretty effective as the executive branch jumped through several dozen hoops to work-around this amendment; with an ensuing scandal.

Answer (score 14):

It can't and therefore doesn't.

Occasionally this comes to light. [A large amount of money related to the rebuilding of Iraq was simply stolen.](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2007/feb/08/usa.iraq1)

Comment: ... and usually we find out about it years later when prosecuting anyone is hard, so at most one or two junior officials will be sent to jail, with the rest walking off scot free.

Comment: I read that article and don't see any indication that was a black program. Yes, it was rife with FW&A, but not a black program. This doesn't answer the question. (or did I completely miss something?)

Comment: This answer seems like citing Enron to answer how corporate accounting can ensure proper oversight of a budget - one example of failure doesn't mean success is impossible. Yes, there are plenty of examples where budgets *are not* spent appropriately, but that is not an indication that oversight cannot be, or is not, done. It's hard to prove a negative that oversight cannot be done, but you certainly can't do it with one example.